# change label text on button click inside a listview item

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview, listadapter

I have a `listview` item with a `label` and two `buttons`. I tried to change the label on button click. But it's changing text on another listview item. Not the label with button. I did this using a custom list adapter. I tried it like following,

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final MenuItem listItem = objects.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);

        btnPlus = (ButtonRectangle) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
        btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = 0;
                cartQtyTextView.setText("" + ++i);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

How may I fix this?

Comment: Can you replace listview with recycler view?

Comment: Do you create a holder ? For the TextView and button?

Comment: @RKNP what is the issue with ListView? Can't it be done with ListView?

Comment: @RKNP - I don't have a view named `recycler view`.
@nicholas - nope.

Comment: where you defining cartQtyTextView

Comment: @PareshMayani we can do it from the listview. But recylerview is the preferable now.so just mentioned that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to create holder. 
I didn't include your menu item code due to i didn't see you got use it.

```
public class Holder {
    ButtonRectangle buttonPlus;
    TextView cartQtyTextView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // Get Holder
    final Holder holder = new Holder();

    // Change Layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                              .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);

    // Find Control
    holder.buttonPlus = (ButtonRectangle)view.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);
    holder.cartQtyTextView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cartQtyTextView);

    // Check & Set
    if (holder.buttonPlus != null) {
        holder.buttonPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int i = 0;
                if (holder.cartQtyTextView != null) {
                    holder.cartQtyTextView.setText("" + ++i);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: thanks. this works.. What's happening here?(with a holder)

Comment: You might want to read this for holder http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder .

Comment: Hmm can you update your code to full code for the extend adapter ?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are setting the listener inside the `if(convertView==null)`.

So the listener is only set once a view is created, but when you scroll, the list view is reusing a hidden item, but it keep the first assigned listener since the convertView is not null.

You need to set your `onClickListener` outside the if. And it is better if you use a [holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html#ViewHolder) for better performances

Answer (score 0):

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MenuItem> {

private Activity activity;
private int resource;
private List<MenuItem> objects;

public ExampleAdapter(Activity activity, int resource, List<MenuItem> objects) {
    super(activity, resource, objects);

    this.activity = activity;
    this.resource = resource;
    this.objects= objects;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    MenuItem listItem = objects.get(position);
    ViewHolder holder = null;

    if (convertView == null) {

        holder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = li.inflate(resource, parent, false);

        holder.labelTextView= (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.labelTextView);
        holder.btnPlus= (ButtonRectangle) convertView.findViewById(R.id.buttonPlus);

        convertView.setTag(holder);

    } else {

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.btnPlus.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int i = 0;
            holder.labelTextView.setText("" + ++i);

        }
    });

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {

    TextView labelTextView;
    ButtonRectangle btnPlus;

}
```

}

Comment: this is a copy of  `nicholas` answer.. No new to learn.. thank you btw